# Checking VBScript for syntax errors without actually running the script

Tags: script, vbscript

I have a script in VBScript. I'm not sure if it contains any syntax errors or other non-runtime errors. Normally I would just run the script, but I don't want the script to actually *run* because the changes it makes are hard to reverse correctly.

Is it possible to make W/CScript check for syntax errors but not run the script if none were found?

I didn't know if this was better suited for SO but I thought it was more WScript specific, as my question lies with WSCript and not the script itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those that like to know how I worked around this:

The majority of the script were subs and functions, with only a few lines of code that were executed on startup. I moved those lines into a Sub Main, and places a line to call Main on the first line.

If I needed to check for syntax errors, I could comment the line that calls Sub Main so no code would be executed.